# Не могу собрать tesseract на MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

Здраствуйте, решил собрать tesseract вот по [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126834/), но при финальной сборке либы вылетает ошибка:

```
    $ ./configure CFLAGS='-D__MSW32__ -O2' CXXFLAGS='-D__MSW32__-O2' LIBS='-                                                                lws2_32
    ' LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR='/mingw/include' --prefix=/mingw
    checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
    checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
    checking --enable-graphics argument... yes
    checking --enable-embedded argument... no
    checking --enable-visibility argument... no
    checking --enable-multiple-libraries argument... no
    checking whether to use tessdata-prefix... yes
    checking whether to enable debugging... no
    ...
    checking for strerror... yes
    checking for vsnprintf... yes
    checking for gethostname... no
    checking for strchr... yes
    checking for memcpy... yes
    checking for acos... yes
    checking for asin... yes
    checking for leptonica... yes
    checking for pixCreate in -llept... no
    configure: error: leptonica library missing
```

Все ставил по инструкции. Использовал jpeg-8c, libpng-1.5.4, tiff-3.9.5 и leptonica-1.68. Пробивал собрать с leptonica-1.73, но результат тот же. Подскажите если кто раньше работал этой библиотекой или компилятором. Спасибо.

Вот что я нашел в config.log:

```
...
configure:17096: checking for leptonica
configure:17115: result: yes
configure:17117: checking for pixCreate in -llept
configure:17142: g++ -o conftest.exe -D__MSW32__-O2  -        I/mingw/include/leptonica  conftest.cpp -llept  -lws2_32 >&5
<command-line>:0:10: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot     find -llept
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:17142: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "tesseract"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tesseract"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.02.02"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "tesseract 3.02.02"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/list"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "tesseract"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.02.02"
| #define PACKAGE_YEAR "2012"
| #define PACKAGE_DATE "10/23"
| #define MINGW 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| #define PACKAGE "tesseract"
| #define VERSION "3.02.02"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
| #define HAVE_LIMITS_H 1
| #define HAVE_MALLOC_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1
| #define HAVE_WCHAR_T 1
| #define HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT 1
| #define HAVE_MBSTATE_T 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H 1
| #define HAVE_GETPAGESIZE 1
| #define vfork fork
| #define HAVE_STRERROR 1
| #define HAVE_VSNPRINTF 1
| #define HAVE_STRCHR 1
| #define HAVE_MEMCPY 1
| #define HAVE_ACOS 1
| #define HAVE_ASIN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char pixCreate ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return pixCreate ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:17151: result: no
configure:17161: error: leptonica library missing
...
```

и в чем тут ошибка?

Comment: Посмотрите, есть ли что-нибудь интересное в configure.log?

Comment: ок, ответ уже написал

Comment: подскажите в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже что в [FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#leptonica-library-missing) есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Нужно указать путь к llept в переменных окружения, примерно так:

```
LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/mingw/include ./configure
```

или так:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/mingw/include" LDFLAGS="-L/mingw/lib" ./configure
```

Для этого разумеется leptonica должна уже быть успешно установлена с `--prefix=/mingw`

У вас `LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR` похоже что указан после `./configure`, что не является правильным синтаксисом установки переменных окружения.

Плюс, там какие-то непонятные проблелы, но это наверное артефакты копирования из cmd.

Comment: извините, но я не совсем понимаю что такое переменная окружения?

Comment: при сборке tesseract я использывал команду: ./configure CFLAGS='-D__MSW32__ -O2' CXXFLAGS='-D__MSW32__-O2' LIBS='-lws2_32' LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR='/mingw/include' --prefix=/mingw

Comment: Переменная среды́ (англ. environment variable) — текстовая переменная операционной системы, хранящая какую-либо информацию — например, данные о настройках системы.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B

Вы пытаетесь передать параметр `CFLAGS='...'` в скрипт `./configure`, а нужно именно установить переменную в нужное значение. Это делается с помощью `VARIABLE='value' command`

Comment: при сборке leptonica использывал команду: ./configure CFLAGS='-O2' CXXFLAGS='-O2' --prefix=/mingw

Comment: ясно, спасибо) )

Comment: это мне надо добавить в строчку в скрипт ./configure? А какое значение мне ему присвоить?

Comment: нет, это именно так нужно запускать ./configure. Т.е. вместо `./configure <...>` нужно именно писать `LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/mingw/include ./configure ...`

Comment: так мне писать: VARIABLE='-D__MSW32__ -O2' command LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR='/mingw/include' ./configure  CXXFLAGS='-D__MSW32__-O2' LIBS='-lws2_32'  --prefix=/mingw ?

Comment: Нужно буквально скопировать команду из моего ответа и вставить ее в терминал. Возможно добавив `--prefix=/mingw` в конце.

Пожалуйста, прочитайте какое-нибудь руководство по работе в консоли unux/linux, будет гораздо понятнее что происходит.

Comment: нет, не помогло. Пишет: checking for leptonica... configure: error: leptonica not found. Использовал команду: LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include ./configure

Comment: при использовании команды: LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/mingw/include ./configure вылетает та же ошибка что и в первый раз((

Comment: какие еще варианты могут быть?